# Si son iguales a un valor en particular, cómo eliminar elementos en vectores de characters usando solamente Base R?

Tags: r

Supongamos que quiero eliminar lo que está en el character vector ***element*** del character vector ***objetivo***.

```
elemento <- c("naranja")   

objetivo <- c("manzana", "pera", "naranja")    
    
is.element(objetivo, elemento) 

#produce lo siguiente:
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#Ahora los combinamos
objetivo[!is.element(objetivo, elemento)]

#produce lo siguiente:
#[1] "manzana" "pera" 
# Que es también un character vector
```

Tuve que sufrir bastante para encontrar la función ***is.element()***

***Hay otras maneras de hacerlo?***

Comment: Dependiendo de la complejidad de lo que deseas hacer, puedes usar `%in%` o realizar una comparación con cada elemento, en este caso buscar todo lo que sea diferente al objeto elemento, de la forma: `objetivo[elemento != objetivo]`

Comment: @rral Muchísimas gracias! No sabía ese truco. Deberías publicarlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser con la intersección `%in%`

```
objetivo[!objetivo %in% elemento]
```

Comment: Genial! Pensé que %in% no era parte de Base R por cuanto %in% se parece a %>% del tidyverse.